# Multiple forms in a single view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, view, model

I have multiple `@Html.BeginForm`'s in my strongly-type View, which inherits from one Model. Some of the fields in the Model are `[Required]` and some are not. When the second `@Html.BeginForm` is submitted, it did not include some of the `[Required] Html.TextBoxFor` items from the first `@Html.BeginForm`. As a result the validation message is showing in the first `@Html.BeginForm` block.

It would be nice if each `@Html.BeginForm` could inherit from different Models, to produce independent sets of `TextBoxFor` and `ValidationFor`.

**Question:** Does anyone know how to suppress the validation in the first form when submitting the second form?

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you just have one controller that handle all of your form. first of all you need to check what form is empty like this:

```
@{

    if(!Request["form1"].IsEmpty()){
        //sending data form 1...
    }
    if(!Request["form2"].IsEmpty()){
        //sending data form 2
    }
    if(!Request["form3"].IsEmpty()){
        //sending data form 3
    }

}
```

It's best practice to separate the controller or method for each form.

Comment: Yes I have separate methods for each form, but they are within one controller, which also controls 3 or 4 other views. I think the next set of Views may need a new controller, we'll see

Comment: Just some Thought that maybe useful for you, if you ended up custom your validation, why not just handle the validation on client side first, and then on server?

Comment: Sure I suppose could do that with custom JQuery .blur(function())  but not with the built-in MVC ValidationMessageFor. Yes this is all just a matter of time, once the system is established I would go back and add client-side validation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to avoid conditional logic in my View. I think the validator does not behave as I expected on multiple forms within a page. So I ended up removing the validators and [Required] fields alltogether and added manual validation within the controller that looks like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (mm.field1 == null)
    sb.Append("<li>field1 is required</li>");
if (mm.field2 == null)
    sb.Append("<li>field2 is required</li>");

//    .... and on and on

if (sb.ToString != "")
   {
    ViewData["validationMessage1"] = "<ul>" + sb.ToString() + "</ul>";
    return View("MyView",mm);
   }

//  Process form below here, at this point all required fields have passed validation
```